# Can I get value from /info/{login}?

Tags: java, spring, http

I have this class

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/info/{login}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getLogin() {
       String login = ?
       return login;
    }
}
```

Can I parse somehow value of {login}?

For example:

```
http://localhost:8080/info/1234
```

my method return "1234";

```
http://localhost:8080/info/298
```

my method return "298".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare a variable for the login value and annotate that with `@PathVariable`:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/info/{login}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody String getLogin(@PathVariable("login") String login) {
    return login;
  }
}
```

Baeldung has good explanations about the powerful options: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping#path-variable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get that value. Replace your code by below.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/info/{login}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getLogin(@PathVariable String login) {
   return login;
}
```